# Image in Storyboard LaunchScreen isn't retina

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm creating a launchscreen with Storyboard, and am using a UIImageView. I specify the image named, and when my app opens, the launch screen shows a blurry version of my image (it's not using to 2x version of the image).

I later programmatically show the same image using `[UIImage imageWithName:@"name"]`, and it shows retina as expected.

The image is saved in an Image Assets file, and I specify the @1x, @2x, and @3x versions.

Any ideas?